# How to deploy the same stack across multiple regions using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm new to `AWS CDK`. It looks like we can `cdk bootstrap` and provide multiple regions:

```
cdk bootstrap {accountID}/us-east1 {accountID}/us-west1
```

This creates buckets and roles in each region that are needed to deploy a stack (let's call it `TestStack`).

What I'd like to do is deploy the same stack (aka `TestStack`) in each region. Is this possible with a single `cdk deploy` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried this and it worked for me, in this example I deployed a dynamodb in us-east-1 and north-east-1 region :-

lib/cdk-stackoverflow-stack.ts

```
import { CfnOutput, Duration, Stack, StackProps,RemovalPolicy } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { aws_dynamodb as db } from 'aws-cdk-lib' 

export class CdkStackoverflowStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
 
    const table = new db.Table(this, 'Table', {
     removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
     partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: db.AttributeType.STRING },
    });

  }
}
```

bin/cdk-stackoverflow.ts file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { CdkStackoverflowStack } from '../lib/cdk-stackoverflow-stack';

const tokyoStack = { region: 'ap-northeast-1' };
const usStack = { region: 'us-east-1' };
const app = new cdk.App();
new CdkStackoverflowStack(app, 'CdkStackoverflowStack1', { env: tokyoStack });
new CdkStackoverflowStack(app, 'CdkStackoverflowStack2', { env: usStack });
```

- Bootstrap all the region where you need to deploy the stack
  `cdk bootstrap aws://accountId/us-east-1`
- then deploy using `--all` options since it it has multiple stack

Command I used for confirmation

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks \
  --query 'StackSummaries[?contains(StackName, `CdkStackoverflowStack`)].StackName' \
  --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE UPDATE_COMPLETE \
  --region ap-northeast-1

 //output

[
    
    "CdkStackoverflowStack1"
]

aws cloudformation list-stacks \
  --query 'StackSummaries[?contains(StackName, `CdkStackoverflowStack`)].StackName' \
  --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE UPDATE_COMPLETE \
  --region us-east-1 

//output 

[
    "CdkStackoverflowStack2"
]
```

Comment: Thanks. This indeed works. However, I noticed you are creating two stacks (of the same type) with different names. So, perhaps there is currently no way to create a stack with the same name across regions?

Comment: Yes right now no way to create stack with same name across regions, because logical ID's should be different across stacks,` Identifiers must be unique within the scope in which they are created; they do not need to be globally unique in your AWS CDK application.` docs -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html
if the answer helped, can you accept it as a solution so that it help others in the future